# Function when webpage is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a website and need to trigger a function when the webpage is not scrolling.

Something like:

```
$("window").notscroll(function() {
    //stuffhere
});
```

Answer can be in either javascript or jQuery.

Hopefully this is possible!

Comment: So when I'm sitting here not scrolling, will this just fire over and over every cycle?

Comment: @MarkMeyer the event was just to change an element of css so it wouldnt matter if it fired constantly

Comment: @alix *the event was just to change an element of css..* this is your problem, and this should be the post, not the solution you intent to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve but you can use **JQuery Debounce** to detect when the user stopped scrolling. Combine this when document first loads if you also need to change css on document load.

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('It is SCROLLING.');
}));
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('DONE SCROLLING!');
}));
```